# Analysis of design of experiments with binary response

Tags: r, anova, experiment-design

Having a hard time determining the best way to analyze this DOE, as I'm generally used to outputs in a different format and with numeric responses.

I've essentially got 2 variables at 3 levels and a summary table with the type of failures at each combination, something like this:

```
A     B     numSamples failA failB failC
1     1            100     2    12    62
2     1            100     3     3    23
3     1            100     1    21    31
1     2            100     2     2    22
2     2            100     3    34    13
3     2            100     1     1    11
1     3            100     2     2    22
2     3            100     9    19     9
3     3            100     8     8    18
```

I need to find the factors/combinations with the most significant contributions, most examples I'm finding apply to numeric response and I'm frankly at a loss for where to begin. Am suspecting that I might need to mutate the data in some way before analysis.. but I'm pulling up on a dead end.

Appreciate any comments/assistance.

---

Additional info:
An item can only fail in one particular way (failA OR failB OR failC). If an object fails, the failure is then classified into one of these categories. For example, you could think of these as A = failure by inconsistent shape, B = failure by cracked outer surface, C = failure by too large size. etc.
Note it is sometimes possible to have multiple failures but there is only one recorded.

By significance of their contribution I'm looking for something akin to an `r^2` in a LM. For example, if there is a general trend that for `B=3` increases `failA` (i.e. what's the coefficient of `failA`?)

At this point I'm leaning towards manipulating this raw data to a long format along the lines of:

```
A  B  Failure  Type
1  1  TRUE     A
1  1  FALSE    NA
1  1  TRUE     C
...
2  1  TRUE     B
...
```

And then performing a logistic regression via glm.
Not certain this is the best approach yet.

Answer (score 1):

If these are your actual data, the table you display tells a pretty clear story already. You want to avoid the `A1,B1` combination that fails three-quarters of the time. There are few `failA` failures, and `failC` failures predominate with a few exceptions (`A2,B2`,`A2,B3`). The `A3,B2` combination seems superior, showing only half the overall failure rate of its nearest competitors, `A1,B3` and `A1,B2`.

If you need a more formal examination, your data have the structure of a [*multinomial* response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) instead of a binary response. There are 4 mutually exclusive outcomes for each test,* including "no failure" as an outcome, and there is no intrinsic ordering among all 4 outcomes. Those are set up as a set of binary regressions against a reference outcome level, done in a way that ensures probabilities adding up to 1 (not ensured with separate logistic regressions).

If you use "no failure" as the reference outcome level, you get models for the log-odds versus "no failure" for each of the `fail` types. Even if you think that the levels of predictors `A` and `B` are ordered, your data suggest that you should evaluate them as unordered factors and include interactions between `A` and `B`.

This [UCLA web page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/) illustrates the procedure for R. The software used on that page will even accept data essentially in the tabular format you show (once you calculate the "no failure" numbers), accepting a matrix of counts as the outcome. You do have to do some work to put together the regression coefficients to describe differences between prediction scenarios, illustrated on that page. Links for multinomial regression with other software are on [this page](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/dae/).

Although you think of `A` and `B` as predictors, it's logically similar to treat the problem as a 3-dimensional contingency table and use a Poisson or related [count model](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/dae/) with the counts as outcomes. You formally treat the `fail` type as a categorical "predictor" in the regression, along with the `A` and `B` categorical predictors, and include all interactions among `A`, `B` and the `fail` types for what's sometimes called ["log-linear" analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-linear_analysis). With exactly 100 tests for each combination of `A` and `B` levels, you only need to include counts (and "predictor" levels) for the 3 `fail` types. Again, you will get a large set of regression coefficients, but their scales will be in terms of log-counts rather than log-odds.

---

*This ignores the possibility of multiple failure types with only 1 recorded. You have to use your knowledge of the subject matter to decide if that's good enough.